# Python - Reply to an email

Tags: python, email, smtp

I want to reply to a specific message using python and smtp.
I've already seen these posts:

[Reply to email using python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433633/reply-to-email-using-python-3-4/31513615#31513615?newreg=35dfc90756ce4400a91687718a134d39)

[How do I reply to an email using the Python imaplib and include the original message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182196/how-do-i-reply-to-an-email-using-the-python-imaplib-and-include-the-original-mes)

But unfortunately, it only sends a reply with this '--------- Forwarded message ----------' instead of replying in the normal way.

Please help!

The code is attached

```
def reply_to_msg(self, original_msg, reply_body):
    # fetch msg
    self.login_imap(host="imap.gmail.com", port=993, username='username@gmail.com', password="pass",
                  use_ssl=True)
    # Filter by subject because it is unique subject (uuid)
    # Get message ID
    mail_ids = self.receive_mail_ids(subject_filter=original_msg["Subject"])

    msg = MIMEMultipart("mixed")
    body = MIMEMultipart("alternative")

    text, _ = self.append_orig_text(reply_body, "", original_msg, True)

    body.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(body)
    msg.attach(MIMEMessage(original_msg))

    msg["Message-ID"] = email.utils.make_msgid()
    msg['To'] = original_msg["From"]
    msg['Subject'] = "Re: " + original_msg["Subject"]
    msg['In-Reply-To'] = msg['References'] = mail_ids[-1]

    # send
    try:
        s = self.login_smtp(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=465, username='username@gmail.com', password="pass", use_ssl=True, use_auth=True)
        self.smtp.sendmail(original_msg['To'], [original_msg["From"]], msg.as_string())
    except Exception as error:
        raise EmailManagerError("sendmail: {}".format(error))

@staticmethod
def append_orig_text(text, html, orig, google=False):
    """
    Append each part of the orig message into 2 new variables
    (html and text) and return them. Also, remove any
    attachments. If google=True then the reply will be prefixed
    with ">". The last is not tested with html messages...
    """
    newhtml = ""
    newtext = ""

    for part in orig.walk():
        if (part.get('Content-Disposition')
                and part.get('Content-Disposition').startswith("attachment")):
            part.set_type("text/plain")
            part.set_payload("Attachment removed: %s (%s, %d bytes)"
                             % (part.get_filename(),
                                part.get_content_type(),
                                len(part.get_payload(decode=True))))
            del part["Content-Disposition"]
            del part["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]

        if part.get_content_type().startswith("text/plain"):
            newtext += "\n"
            newtext += part.get_payload(decode=False)
            if google:
                newtext = newtext.replace("\n", "\n> ")

        elif part.get_content_type().startswith("text/html"):
            newhtml += "\n"
            newhtml += part.get_payload(decode=True).decode("utf-8")
            if google:
                newhtml = newhtml.replace("\n", "\n> ")

    if newhtml == "":
        newhtml = newtext.replace('\n', '<br/>')

    return (text + '\n\n' + newtext, html + '<br/>' + newhtml)
```

Comment: What sort of reply would you like to send? Omitting the original message should be an easy enough exercise.

Comment: Reply in the same way as the 'reply' button does in the Gmail app. Not 'Forwarded message'.